# How do I Create Objects with a Prompt?

Tags: javascript, object, prompt

The question says it all. Is it even possible for the user to create new objects by responding to a prompt? And if it is possible, then could I also add properties to those objects? (Instructions on this, too, please.

The reason why I'm asking this is because I'm currently doing a school project involving a small database showing our understanding of objects, arrays, and such. I'm not very experienced in Javascript, so a somewhat straightforward answer would be great.

I've noticed a lot of the responses from people on this site include parts of Javascript I don't understand / haven't learned yet.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Do you need us to complete your school project on your behalf by any chance ?

Comment: you did mention that they want to check your understanding of objects, arrays. I think that expectation says it all. first of try to learn it, do lots of google if you aren't getting it clearly. I believe that's what your teacher is expecting from you!

Comment: @klugjo No, I've got most of it figured out, thank you. That would be dishonest anyway. I just needed slight clarification on if I could create objects with prompts, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
var answer = prompt('...')
# now create your object however you want
var obj = new MyObject(answer)
```

Prompt itself can't create any objects, of course. It has only one job and does it well.

Comment: Thank you! So my understanding is "new" can be used to add properties to an object as well?

Comment: @IanHonma: depends on what you mean by that.

Comment: Well, the user is supposed to be able to add objects into this mini-database. I'm wondering if it's possible to prompt them to insert what they want the properties of the object to be, such as color. "What color describes this object?" Say they enter blue. Can I get the database to log a property attached to the new object? I'm sorry if you're still confused; I have difficulty wording things like this.

Comment: @IanHonma: yep, still confused. In any case, prompt has nothing to do with the database. It's just an input device.

Answer (score 0):

```
var car = new Object();
car["color"] = prompt("Enter the car color name:");
console.log(car);
```